# Case when then in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use `case when then` in `where` clause if one of the conditions is fulfilled?What I need is if there is only one condition to be executed after the first condition is met If a condition meets the following conditions, it will not be executed.The case statement will stop evaluating further as soon as the first when condition is met

```
SELECT TOP 100 ProjType, projCost, InvestAmount, ProjBuildSize
FROM dbo.Project 
WHERE
   (
     CASE
     WHEN projCost > 0  then projCost end >= 10000000 
     WHEN InvestAmount IS NOT NULL then InvestAmount end >= 12000000
     WHEN ProjBuildSize > 0 then ProjBuildSize ELSE >= 5000
     END
   )
```

Comment: You wanted an `OR` condition ?

Comment: FYI: `InvestAmount <> NULL` won't work as you intend, it should be `InvestAmount is not NULL`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `CASE WHEN` here, a simple x `OR` y `OR` z will suffice.

Also, if `InvestAmount` is a nullable column, then to check for null you must do `InvestAmount IS NOT NULL` instead of `InvestAmount <> NULL`

```
SELECT TOP 100 ProjType,projCost,InvestAmount,ProjBuildSize 
FROM dbo.Project 
WHERE
    (projCost > 0 AND projCost >= 10000000)
    OR (InvestAmount IS NOT NULL AND InvestAmount >= 12000000)
    OR (WHEN ProjBuildSize > 0 AND ProjBuildSize  >= 5000)
```

Comment: What I need is if there is only one condition to be executed after the first condition is met

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `case` statement like this in your `where` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ProjType, projCost, InvestAmount, ProjBuildSize
FROM dbo.Project 
WHERE
   (
     CASE
     WHEN projCost > 0 AND projCost >= 10000000 then 1  
     WHEN InvestAmount IS NOT NULL AND InvestAmount >= 12000000 then 1
     WHEN ProjBuildSize > 0 AND ProjBuildSize >= 5000 then 1
     ELSE 0
     END
   ) = 1
```

If any of your `when` conditions are satisfied, the `case` will return a `1`, and the `where` clause condition will be satisfied, otherwise the `case` will return `0`.

Comment: What I need is if there is only one condition to be executed after the first condition is met

Comment: @beiduoan The `case ` statement automatically stops evaluating as soon as a `when` condition is met, so the query I wrote will work.

Comment: You're welcome, please feel free to upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```
SELECT TOP 100 ProjType,projCost,InvestAmount,ProjBuildSize FROM dbo.Project 
WHERE (projCost <= 0 OR projCost >= 10000000)
      AND (projCost <= 0 And ((InvestAmount is null)  OR InvestAmount >= 12000000))
      AND ((InvestAmount is null And projCost <= 0) And ((ProjBuildSize <= 0 ) OR ProjBuildSize  >= 5000))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @beiduoan

Comment: What I need is if there is only one condition to be executed after the first condition is met

Comment: I've just updated my answer, Please take a look @beiduoan